# Looking for a Maggid Meisharim with footnotes/he'arot

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, malach-angel

I'm looking for an edition of Rav Yosef Karo's Maggid Meisharim that has footnotes as well as some sort of scholarly historical background to the sefer. Does anyone know of something like that?

Comment: Seforim stores in Brooklyn. Mizrachi books. Pinter's in Boro Park. And now, Miyodeya.

Comment: Did you try asking them? Did they know anything, similar editions; one with a commentary, but no critical introduction, etc.? | Note that it [is debated](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56940/8775) whether R. Karo actually authored the work in question.

Comment: @MarkA. You should always [edit] relevant info into the question.

Comment: Raphael Judah Werblowsky wrote a wonderful book in English on R. Karo with a focus on the MM; its authorship, credibility and some discourses on different themes in the book. The book is called '[Joseph Karo Lawyer and Mystic](https://www.amazon.com/Joseph-Karo-R-Zwi-Werblowsky/dp/0827600909)'.